# How to get ContextMenuItem x and y coordinates

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flexbuilder

i build a contextmenu i want when user click any item then i get the x and y coordinate of the contextmenuitem............actully  i  want to dispaly a textbox infornt of contextmenuitem when user click on the item........ or any other solution that i will show inputtext control as submenuitem in contextmenuitem

Comment: did you figure out this one? did any of the answers below help you? If so, accept the correct one, please

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of doing what you are asking for is:

- disallow the right-click mouse in the
  html container with javascript
- capture right-click events and
  forward them to flash via
  ExternalInterface
- In the method
  triggered from ExternalInterface,
  do/show what you want.

There are some open source solutions:

- [custom-context-menu](http://code.google.com/p/custom-context-menu/)
- [Article at ADM blog](http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/right-click-and-custom-context-menu-in-flash-flex/)

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener to each menu item.  In the listener function, the event's target object is the object you clicked on - all you need to do is cast it to DisplayObject, and you can access the x and y coordinates:

```
contextmenuItem.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, onItemClick);

function onItemClick (ev:MouseEvent) : void {
   var item:DisplayObject = ev.target as DisplayObject;
   // use item.x and item.y to get the object's position.
}
```

Comment: uh, i think you misunderstood the question...ContextMenuItems do not extends DisplayObject.

Comment: @Goliatone: The guy says: I built a contextmenu.  So I figured it's a thing he actually built, not the one that opens on the flash player -  and anything that's on the stage extends DisplayObject.

Comment: perhaps you are right! Just guessing that he's not a native speaker and that was my interpretation. Did not mean the comment to read so negatively.

Comment: @goliatone: Me neither ;) Well, let's wait and see if he reacts!

Comment: i mean that on click contextmenu will display